# how long does it take for CBCentralManager to stop scanning?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I want to stop, then restart scanning on a CBCentralManager. My question is: should I wait awhile for the transaction to settle after calling stopScanning(), or can I make my startScanning() call immediately?

I don't know how responsive the lower layers and hardware are.

Approach 1:

```
    self.stopScanning()
    self.startScanning()
```

Approach 2:

```
    self.stopScanning()

    // wait a few secs for the BLE layer to shutdown to be safe...
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) {
       // ...now resume scanning
       self.startScanning()
    }
```

Comment: Check the `isScanning` property.

Answer (score 2):

Either a small delay after stopScan() before scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:) or monitoring the isScanning property would likely work with what your question is asking.

The other consideration I would have is that BLE is designed for minimum power consumption and scanning is a very power hungry process that should be done as little as possible. The first item from Apple under [Best Practices for Interacting with a Remote Peripheral Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html) is about how to avoid scanning or minimize the time/power consumption of scanning. So it's also important to take that into consideration as part of the application design as well.

Comment: I understand that continuous scanning is a no-no for BLE. However, I have been tasked with writing a BLE 'sniffer' app - so I believe I must be scanning continuously (or close). It seems like the app requirements directly contradict BLE best practices.

Comment: Makes total sense. That's one of a few cases that the rules go out the window. Good luck on the app.